# Ubuntu touch preview nmcli connection for 3G data throws an error

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I tried to setup a 3g data connection on ubuntu touch preview (latest raring build)

But if I try to start with "nmcli con up "O2 connection 1"  I get the error:

Unknown parameter: O2 connection 1
ERROR: id or uuid has to be specified

Here is my config file created from nm-connection-editor:

[connection]

id=O2 connection 1

uuid=ec4ef9f6-f466-4e18-b250-4437b208bd45

type=gsm

autoconnect=false

[gsm]
number=*99#

apn=internet

network-type=0

[ipv4]
method=auto

[serial]

baud=115200

Can someone help me with this issue?

id and uuid are in the config file.

Thanx a lot !!!

Greets
andi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `con up` you need to provide id or uuid, but you need to specify also if next parameter is "id" or "uuid".

Short answer: you need to add **id** parameter before id value:

```
nmcli con up id "O2 connection 1"
```

instead of:

```
nmcli con up "O2 connection 1"    # <--- missing "id"
```

Comment: OHHH shame on me :-(
yepp i forgot this...but now I got the error "Unknown connection" 

What could that be?

Comment: I would try via uuid. BTW, I see you are new here. Remember to upvote, and select best answer :-)

Comment: Oh sorry Michal - how do I do this?

Comment: OK - I tried

nmcli con up uiid "O2 connection 1"

but same error :-(.....UNKNOWN CONNECTION